# Which component renders child component if parent is componentless

Tags: angular

Which component is used to display children components if the parent path does not have any component
like in the example below (which component will render `ScheduleListComponent` component).

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',  
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ScheduleListComponent },
      { path: 'function/:id', component: ScheduleFunctionComponent },
      { path: 'schedules/:id', component: ScheduleComponent },
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: The first component in your component tree which has a router-outlet. This construction would necessitate you having a router-outlet in your `app.component`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no component assosiated with   It wil be rendered in parent router-outlet, normally this pattern is called component less routes.

Componentless routes “consume” URL segments without instantiating components.

Now, when navigating to ’/function/1’, the router will create the following component tree:

```
AppComponent -> ScheduleFunctionComponent
```

[For more information](https://www.google.com/amp/s/vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes/amp)